Using Excel to make scatter plot reverencing all three axis to single point
I have three data sets. Speed, Torque and efficiency. I want to create a graph that shows relation between all three. So, like I want a point to reflect at what speed and torque what kind of efficiency we had. With the Current options I see, It gives me two data series separately one with relation of Speed and efficiency and other with Torque and efficiency.  Can there be a way that a single point in the chart shows all three together.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You talk about making a scatter plot. This is on of the chart options in Excel. Have you tried it? If yes, how does it fail to achieve what you want?

There are many ways you can visualize three variables.
You can try using a bubble chart:

But these are rarely easy to understand.
Or create a range for efficiency and use it as the color coding on a bivariate scatter plot. Chart not shown.

Generally you have to decide what you are trying to show (beyond "the relationship between the three variables").
You could try:

Small multiples
Parallel plot
Heat map (with efficiency as the color intensity)

What you choose will depend on the structure of your data and the goals of your analysis.
